# Is would necessary here?

Tags: will-would

I was afraid that this book sold out very fast.

I was afraid that this book would sell out very fast.

Are both sentences correct? What is the meaning each one convey?

Comment: Your first example is invalid as a *past* tense utterance, but note that *present* tense ***I am afraid that** this book sold out very fast* is perfectly natural English. It's an ***idiom***, used in polite/formal contexts - for example, by a bookseller apologizing to a customer who wants to buy a book, but there are none left in stock because they sold quicker than expected. Your *second* example sounds like something a potential *customer* might say, with the implication that if he wants t buy a copy he'd better hurry up, otherwise the bookshop *will* have sold out.

Comment: The idiom ***I'm afraid** that X [is true]* is equivalent to ***I regret to inform you** that X is true*.

Answer (score 1):

**I was afraid...**.

At some time in the past, I feared something.

What did you fear?

**...that this book **sold out** very fast*

No, you cannot be afraid of something that happened in the past. You must be afraid of something that could happen soon, in the future.

Your fear was that the book **"will sell out"** very fast.

Those words in quotes were your exact words *at the time*. You said it to everyone. "That book will sell out, I know it. I won't be able to buy that book. Darn!  That book will sell out. I am so unlucky!"

But now, you are telling us about the fear you had, and you are not quoting your exact words, and you therefore must change "will" to "would".

**I feared that the book *would* sell out very fast.**

That is how to talk about your fear of a future event, when the fear was something you felt in the past.

Answer (score 1):

"afraid" has a variety of non-literal meanings.

It is sometimes used just as a form of apology. So "I'm afraid that this book sold out" is roughly the same as "I'm sorry.  This book sold out". But that requires a present tense "afraid".

In the past it can express a concern that may not be realised. Consistency of tense means you should use would:  "I was afraid that this book would sell out"  = I was worried that this book would sell out."  In context you would understand if the book had really sold out or not.

Answer (score 0):

> I was afraid that this book **sold out**

is ungrammatical. If the book *sold out* at some point before the present, your past self may or may not know that; to be meaningful, everything your past self thought about has to be relative to that moment in the past.

> I was afraid that this book **would sell out**

is valid, and

> I was afraid that this book **had sold out**

is valid, but the meanings are different. The first expresses uncertainty *about the future* in a past reference frame. The second expresses uncertainty about *unknown present information* in a past reference frame.

Ordinarily, you could say these both in the present too:

> I'm afraid that this book **will sell out** very fast.

> I'm afraid that this book **has sold out** very fast.

But as FumbleFingers points out in a comment, "I'm afraid" is an idiom meaning "I regret to inform you," so you'd have to rephrase to keep the same meaning.